# Почему не уходит запрос на сервер?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

Всем привет! Делаю пост запрос, но он не доходит, вот , что возвращается

```
{System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: NotFound. ---> System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: NotFound.
   at System.Net.Browser.ClientHttpWebRequest.InternalEndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Net.Browser.ClientHttpWebRequest.<>c__DisplayClasse.<EndGetResponse>b__d(Object sendState)
   at System.Net.Browser.AsyncHelper.<>c__DisplayClass1.<BeginOnUI>b__0(Object sendState)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.Browser.AsyncHelper.BeginOnUI(SendOrPostCallback beginMethod, Object state)
   at System.Net.Browser.ClientHttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at PhoneApp2.MainPage.<>c__DisplayClass2.<Button_Click>b__1(IAsyncResult r)
   at System.Net.Browser.ClientHttpWebRequest.<>c__DisplayClass1d.<InvokeGetResponseCallback>b__1b(Object state2)}
```

Вот кусок когда, который реализовывает запрос:

```
SystemTray.ProgressIndicator = new ProgressIndicator();
                SystemTray.ProgressIndicator.Text = "Loading,please wait...";
                this.SetProgressIndicator(true);
                string email = emailB.Text;
                string password = passwordB.Password;
                string postdata = "pa=" + password + "&em=" + email + "&os=android";
                bool is_correct = false;

                HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("Тут адрес моего сервера");

                request.Method = "POST";
                request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";

                request.BeginGetRequestStream(r1 =>
                {

                    HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)r1.AsyncState;
                    // End the stream request operation
                    Stream postStream = req.EndGetRequestStream(r1);

                    byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postdata);

                    postStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
                    postStream.Close();

                    //Start the web request
                    req.BeginGetResponse(r =>
                    {
                        HttpWebRequest request1 = (HttpWebRequest)r.AsyncState;

                        HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request1.EndGetResponse(r);
                        using (StreamReader httpWebStreamReader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
                        {
                            string result = httpWebStreamReader.ReadToEnd();
                            List<authObject> list = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<authObject>>(result);

                            foreach (authObject value in list)
                            {
                                this.user_id = value.auth;
                                this.sess_id = value.sess_id;
                            }
                            Deployment.Current.Dispatcher‏‏.BeginInvoke‏(myCallback);
                        }
                    }, req);
                }, request);

            }
            catch (InvalidCastException e1)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e1.Source);
            }
```

Что это может быть на ваш взгляд?

Comment: @Godfather07 NotFound похоже на ошибку 404. Руками такой запрос проходит? Какой ответ возвращается?

Comment: @Fike да, руками проходит, 200 если не ошибаюсь. ДЕло в том что с этого сервера я беру данные и для iOS и для Android. Все денные теже только вфон вот так ведет себя

Comment: @Godfather07, интернет говорит, что эта ошибка может значить буквально что угодно, и надо включать и смотреть дебаг/фиддлер (хотя не уверен что фиддлер поможет, если возвращается 200). Может, ответ пустой и оно так реагирует.

Comment: @Fike можешь подсказать как включить вебдебаг ? я пытался файлы найти но не нашёл

Comment: @Godfather07, мой опыт с шарпом был очень коротким, к сожалению, и я тут отвечаю больше как мимокрокодил. Навскидку вот http://blogs.msdn.com/b/fiddler/archive/2011/01/09/debugging-windows-phone-7-device-traffic-with-fiddler.aspx?Redirected=true

Чуть позже наверняка ответят более прошаренные люди.